# Javamelody and Play Framework

Tags: playframework, monitoring

Is it possible to monitor Play Framework application performance with Javamelody? I'm using Javamelody with Spring apps. I find it much better than free version of AppDynamics or Dyna Trace.

You can't use filter for HTTP monitoring or aspect for method monitoring. I think I should make something like filter or aspect. I have no idea how to add performance monitoring to JDBC queries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javamelody, but you have to:

1. Generate war file from your play framework web
2. Edit web.xml in war file (http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide?tm=6)
3. Deploy it in container server such as tomcat

Comment: JDbMonitor or other monitoring JDBC proxy is a kind of solution. You reminded me, that Javamelody has that kind of JDBC proxy driver and a special HibernateBatcherFactory for plugging into Hibernate. That leaves HTTP request monitoring and business methods monitoring.

Comment: Yes, Javamelody itself is enough to request JDBC performance. See my updated answer for installing javamelody in your play framework app.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure yet if I want to deploy my app on servlet container. Thanks.

Comment: Seem deploy as war is the only option for using javamelody inside play web apps.

Comment: I'll try to look into javamelody code. Do you think it is possible to create something like filter known from JEE in Play! Something that is executed "around" HTTP request handler. People says you can override rawInvocation() in Plugin. Can't find any documentation.

Comment: There are those "@Before", "@After" and "@Finally" hooks to use.

Comment: Yes, there are annotation that mark an method to be run before, after and finnaly. This annotaion reside in controller. See the link below on interception detail: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/controllers